# Ping is not working on spine leaf topology on mininet

Tags: networking, ping, sdn, mininet, ryu

I am new in mininet and I want to know while I create spin leaf  DataCenter topology and visualiz the topology using RYU controller the ping is not working.
The Topology:

```
                       ____[S1]    
[L1], [L2], [L3]------|
                      |----[S2]
```

3 hosts are attached to each Leaf switch, and each leaf is connected to both Spine Switches. The hosts doesn't ping on each other.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you have some loop in the topo, so make sure to use RYU with STP protocol

The STP protocol can take some minutes (depends on the topology).
This is how I run Ryu with STP (I am using the python3 and OpenFlow 1.3, if you use a different version the path can be different)

```
ryu-manager /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/ryu/app/simple_switch_stp_13.py --verbose
```

Comment: I have used pox controller for this problem and the network started to ping using this command `./pox.py forwarding.l2_multi openflow.discovery` but I can't visualize the network. Is there a GUI for pox controller forwarding.l2_multi to  view the network topology? @Giuseppe

Comment: I didn't use pox for a while, be careful with the number of switches attached. For what I remember pox has a limited amount of switches that can manage (around 16).
Regarding Pox GUI, I am not sure if there is an official one. Searching for a while, i found this on github: https://github.com/lewischeng-ms/pox/blob/master/tools/pox-gui.py but I never tried. Otherwise you can use ONOS, it is written in Java and it is working fine for me (it has a nice GUI and l2 forwarding applications: https://wiki.onosproject.org/display/ONOS/Downloads)